# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeApiServiceUtil;

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-youtube-api

App crashes when the fragment containing below code of a youtube player is executed in Android 5.0 and 5.1 devices. Whereas it works fine in Android 6.0 and above version devices.

Code where crash comes:

```
YouTubeInitializationResult result =
    YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(getActivity());
if (result != YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS) {
    result.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), 0).show();
}
```

GRADLE:

```
 build.gradle dependencies {
           compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
           compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar') androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
       {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
           })
           compile project(':ResideMenu')
           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
           compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
           compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
           compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
           compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
           compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.0'
           compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
           compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
           compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4' }
```

Error Log:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>       Lcom/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeApiServiceUtil;
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeApiServiceUtil"

Comment: Is There any alternative of YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar because in my case the YouTubeApiServiceUtil class is not getting found in YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar at the runtime which make the app crash.These three classes are required for my code to run YouTubeApiServiceUtil,YouTubeInitializationResult,YouTubeStandalonePlayer

Comment: That class is definitely in the JAR I just downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jar file you could try to add the dependency in gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.22.0'
}
```

Comment: actual problem was due to  the google play service entry in gradle compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'.Removed the entry and now working fine.